# IIS and ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 Issues with SharePoint

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, sharepoint

I have just moved a SharePoint 2007 site from one server to another.  Both servers are running Windows Server 2003 R2 Service Pack 2, but the new one is x64 as apposed to x84.  I successfully installed SharePoint and attached the content databases to SQLSERVER and associated them with their respected webpages.

However when I try to view the page, either from outside the server or from within, the page never loads.  I've checked some forums and everyone suggests giving read permissions to the ISS_WPG group win the Inetpub folder. I have done this, but it still doesn't work.
Any suggestions as to why my website won't load?  What are typical problems that block web content from a server?

EDIT: When I say the page never loads, I mean that IE says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage."  In the Application Event Log there is a pile of ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 errors.  When I try to access the site from another computer, I get a Directory Error that says "This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed."

Using aspnet_regiis.exe -lv, I see that I have the asp.net 1.1.4322.0 (x86) and 2.0.50727.0 (x86 and x64) version installed.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint 2007

Comment: When you say "the page never loads", it times out? Any entries in Application event log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try running aspnet_regiis.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx  I noticed that in the past the installation of the .Net Framework 2.0 did not register with IIS on x64.

Answer (score 1):

You might have checked this already, but verify the site and/or virtual directory is set to use .NET 2.0 rather than 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error that means that you are not even able to connect to the IIS site. So you need to start with the basics...

1. Can you ping the server from the client machine?

   ping servername

or...

```
ping fully.qualified.name.com
```

2. Can you telnet the server port from the client machine?

   telnet severname 80

I'm assuming you are using the 80 port.

If any of these commands fail you have a network issue that you need to solve first.

Can you also share some more details about those ASP.NET errors in the event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Here we've got many layers of issues that might be causing this. Sacha established common networking issues, if those don't work try checking the following:

1. Is your Sharepoint 2007 the x64 version? (If not IIS might be running the 32-Bit version of the application, use [Denis Bauer's  ASP.NET Version Switcher](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools.aspx) or try running **cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 true**)
2. Did you configure Alternate Access Mappings **(AAM)** to the new server name?
3. Delete the application in the Central Administration, create a new one, delete the new content database and attach the old one using **stsadm -o addcontentdb -url http://url -databaseserver DBSERVER -databasename**

Hope this helps..